# Can Chart.js provide a "scrolling view" of charts with large amounts of data?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart I'm building that will span over thousands of data points.  I'd like to be able to limit what is shown at any given time by a subset of that data (say 1000 data points at a time).  Is there a way to achieve this directly within chart.js?  The chart is built from data collected at regular time intervals; I want to be able to visualize all data, but would also like to be able to narrow the focus to investigate specific time periods within the overall data.